# Получение Ip от которого пришел запрос

Tags: php

Отправляю курлом запрос на сервер, как можно получить IP с которого был послан реквест?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php

Comment: Использовал REMOTE_ADDR но в нем содержится айпи сервера на который был послан запрос

Comment: А если идёт проброс через прокси, то вы увидите адрес прокси. Тогда IP вы никак не узнаете. Да и если клиент в "локальной" сети, то его адрес тоже не узнаете, а если и узнаете - достучатся не сможете, именно по этому гугл оставляет метки в cookies и следит за пользователями через cookies.

Comment: А как это проверить?

Comment: Допустим у вас два браузера: Опера и IE. Откуда IE знает что страница пришла IE а не Опера? А опера знает что это для неё? Так же само прокси, у него для каждого компа устанавливается своё соидинение. Скорее всего "ответный" порт будет разный, а так различит, создавая по коннекту для каждого компа.

Comment: Может быть вам поможет  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR http://phpfaq.ru/tech/ip